# How to receive iMessages ONLY on the device you are currently using?

Tags: messages, privacy, macos

Is it possible to receive iMessages on the device you are currently using, and only that device.  If so, how?

Background:  I don't want to receive iMessages on my iMac and Macbook Air when I'm not there.  I'd like to restrict iMessages being sent to my phone unless I'm currently using my iMac or Macbook Air.

Answer (score 2):

No - this isn't possible.

You would have to sign out of iMessage entirely on the devices that you wish to not receive notifications.